# Python pandas add value to same row

Tags: python, pandas

How to: in a for loop, insert value at specific column by name, on the same row each time. So I have a few hundred columns. And I want each value to be put on the same row (Using the DATE) in the appropriate column. Here are my dataframe columns:

```
DATE, ABC, BGF, ATR
```

Here is my example value for `List`:

```
[["VAL:ABC", 5, 6, 7], ["VAL:ATR", 7, 43]]
```

Here is my how my dataframe should behave, put the list with the matched first element into the dataframe on a new row.

> ```
> DATE,          ABC,        BGF,        ATR
> 12-01-2011      5           -           -
> ```

On the same row still, put the next list item with the same column header in.

> ```
> DATE,          ABC,        BGF,        ATR
> 12-01-2011      5            -          7
> ```

---

Here's my code so far

```
mod_df = df.append({'Date' : str(currentDate)}, ignore_index=True)

# append new values
for col in df.columns:
    #print(col)
    for aMrket in List_market_data:     # [["VAL:ABC", 5, 6, 7], ["VAL:ATR", 7, 43]]
        if aMrket[1] == str(col): 
            # if column header is the same as the last 3 characters in the list's first item
            # then add to same row (use the date)

            mod_df.loc[mod_df.Date == currentDate, col] = aMrket[-3]
```

## EDIT

The final code line above is what i wanted. i got it

Comment: how does your list look like?

Comment: @smci what do u mean assign?

Comment: I really just need to know how to get the current row im on, so that i can add values for all the columns

Comment: Sorry I meant an ordinary Pandas assignment with `.loc[]`, like `df.loc[:, "ATR" ]`. Please read the [tutorial on assigning and slicing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html). You just need the string to be simply "ATR" instead of "VAL:ATR" so you can index with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit a specific ROW (mod_df.Date)

ONLY where a specific value appears (== currentDate),

on the col (, col)

with this value (= aMrket[-3])

```
mod_df.loc[mod_df.Date == currentDate, col] = aMrket[-3]
```